# OpenCV Vector x Matrix cross correlation

Tags: c++, opencv, simd, cross-correlation

All the open CV examples I can find seem to relate to a 2D kernel over a 2D image.

I have a 1d kernel and am looking for an operation which will return, per row the value and offset which results in the maximum correlation.

Straight C++ my code would look like:

```cpp
    vector<int> offset(img.rows);
    vector<int> amp(img.rows);
    std::vector<double> corrs(MAX_SEARCH);

    for(int row = 0; row< img.rows; row++){
        row_data = img.row(row)
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SEARCH; i++) {
            double correlation = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < wfm.size(); j++) {
                correlation += (wfm[j] * row_data[i+j]);
            }
            corrs[i] = correlation;
        }

        amp[row]  = *std::max_element(corrs.begin(), corrs.end());
        offest[row] = std::max_element(corrs.begin(), corrs.end()) - corrs.begin();
    }
```

The key thing I'm looking for, is to be able to take advantage of some Single Instruction Multiple Data optimizations which I think OpenCV should be able to do, or if OpenCV won't achieve this, how could this code be rewritten to do so.

Comment: `corrs` size is `wfm.size()`, but you're indexing it with `i` (up to MAX_SEARCH) not `j`.  Also, it doesn't need to exist at all; you can just update a `max_corr = max(max_corr, correlation);` in the `i` loop.  And I guess special case the first one.  That might help the compiler do a better job, or might make it worse, you'd have to see if you're hoping for auto-vectorization.

Comment: If you were manually vectorizing with SIMD, you might want to do 4 `i` values at once so you do more work with each `wfm[j]` each time you read it, updating 4 correlation values at once.  Putting `#pragma omp simd` before the `i` loop might be good, to encourage a compiler to vectorize over that middle loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes good catch on the size of corrs, I edited to fix it. I'll look into the #pragma omp simd

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCV functions, then you need to build OpenCV for your machine with the SIMD support. Or you can follow [this solution](https://answers.opencv.org/question/211941/how-to-use-simd-feature-of-opencv-as-third-party-library/) on OpenCV forums.

For your code, might I recommend OpenMP. It's easy to add. You would just add `#pragma omp simd` before the last for loop. Then compile with -fopenmp. [Here](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs3225-GIS/fall16/Lectures/openmp.html) is a simple tutorial to understand OpenMP. And their [documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html) on the simd option.

Comment: Interesting, I thought I OpenCV would always use SSE/SIMD but seems like I may have to recompile the library and add the #define CV_SSE2. ... But I still need to figure out how to port the code to openCV commands.

Comment: The first thing I'm failing to find is the syntax that lets me do the vector multiplication of my wfm which is M cols by1 by a subset of my image ie: corr(N,1) = wfm(M,1) * img(N,M)

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/185681/multiply-vector-by-matrix/) not answer your question?

Comment: almost, the operation is what I'm looking for, however it only works for 2 or 3 element vectors rather than arbitrary vector math.